# GameCenter login screen- cancel button pressed event

Tags: ios, game-center

I present the GameCenter login screen:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
     if (viewController != nil) {
         [self presentViewController:gameCenterLoginController animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
```

And I want to do something after the login screen dismiss.

The login screen can be dismissed in 2 ways:

1. User logged in successfully
2. User dismissed the login screen

How can I catch the dismiss login screen event (second way)?

(And no, the `UIViewController` lifecycle methods doesn't fire- like `viewDidAppear:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did in my projects:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
     if (viewController != nil) {
         [self presentViewController:gameCenterLoginController animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
     else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
     {
       // user is authenticated -  do what next steps
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@“Local player is not authenticated or was canceled”);
         //do thing …
     }
```